# Adapting 1/2 gas line to 3/4 gas grill?

Tags: gas

I have a gas bbq grill with a 3/4" quick connect line, and a gas line on my deck with a 1/2" quick connect input. Is there any way to hook them up?

Comment: Are you able to provide photos? Specific connector type could be relevant.  3/4" sounds _huge_ for a grill. Are you sure?

Comment: Brand & model of the grill with a link to the online documentation would help us help you...

Comment: As far as I can find this is the grill https://www.homedepot.com/p/KitchenAid-4-Burner-Propane-Gas-Grill-in-Stainless-Steel-with-Ceramic-Searing-Side-Burner-and-Rotisserie-Burner-720-0954/300025217 , I got it from someone wanted to throw it out. I'll get pictures as soon as I can. Both the line coming out of the grill and the line on my deck are quick attach.

Answer (score 2):

If the grill *actually needs* a 3/4" feed, 1/2" is going to leave it starved for gas; in that case you'll probably need to run a new gas line to support the grill, or get a different grill that's less needy.

If you retrofitted an oversized quick-connect to the grill for a prior residence, just change it back to a 1/2" quick connect.